# OnRequestPermissionsResult(): no suitable method found to override

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

I currently have the following in a Xamarin.Forms project.

```
public class CameraPageRenderer : PageRenderer, ActivityCompat.IOnRequestPermissionsResultCallback  {
    ...
    public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, Permission[] grantResults) {
        Console.WriteLine("testing callback");
    }
    ...
}
```

Separately, I have the following to request the camera permission.

```
var perms = new string[] {Manifest.Permission.Camera};
ActivityCompat.RequestPermissions((Context as Activity), perms, 0);
```

If I remove "override" from OnRequestPermissionsResult, I do not get any message. Leaving it in, I get the compile error "no suitable method found to override".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will want to implement the `ActivityCompat.IOnRequestPermissionsResultCallback` interface in an `Activity`. Otherwise you will need to provide an application `Context` / `Activity` to the `ActivityCompat.RequestPermissions()` method.

You can read much more here:

[https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ActivityCompat.html#requestPermissions(android.app.Activity, java.lang.String[], int)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ActivityCompat.html#requestPermissions(android.app.Activity,%20java.lang.String[],%20int))

> If your app does not have the requested permissions the user will be presented with UI for accepting them. After the user has accepted or rejected the requested permissions you will receive a callback reporting whether the permissions were granted or not. Your activity has to implement [ActivityCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ActivityCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback.html) and the results of permission requests will be delivered to its [onRequestPermissionsResult(int, String[], int[])](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ActivityCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback.html#onRequestPermissionsResult(int,%20java.lang.String[],%20int[])) method.

Comment: He is passing a context to the `ActivityCompat.RequestPermissions() `. Same issue here

Answer (score 5):

This is interface implementation not inheritance, so just implement it, don't use "override".
Also take a look
https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/PermissionsPlugin